# Rails 2.3.16 upgrade breaks ActiveSupport::JSON.decode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, yaml, json

When i am trying to upgrade Rails to 2.3.16 from 2.3.15, the `ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(response.body)` fails to handle `NaN`. 
Am getting an error like: `invalid character at "NaN,...`

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Related commit/discussion https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/bd6dee9bb9575ab7abfde5dbc95bdd4aa0f79693

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActiveSupport::JSON.decode` uses `MultiJson` under the hood which tends to ignore any passed in options (At least in Rails 3, not sure about 2.3). This means you can't pass in the usually accepted option of `allow_nan`.

However, if you are using Ruby 1.9+ you can use the built-in [JSON](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#parse-method) parser:

```
require 'json'
json_result = JSON.parse(response.body, allow_nan: true)
```